# How many functions are not one-to-one?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am having some trouble starting this question.

If we have two sets. Set A of size m where m≥1 and set B of size n where n≥1. How many of the functions f : A→B are **not** one-to-one?

I know that the total number of functions f : A→B is:  $n^m$

Also that the number of functions that are one-to-one is: n!/(n-m)!

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you know the number of blurgs is 72, and you know the number of green blurgs is 37, can you work out the number of blurgs that are not green?

Comment: I have 176 balls. 61 of them are blue. How many are not blue?

Comment: **Hint**. The total number of functions is the number of ones that are 1-1 plus the number that are not 1-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're already done!  Every function is either one-to-one or not one-to-one; so, if $N$ is the number of all such functions, $N_1$ the number of one-to-one functions, and $N_2$ the number of such functions that ARE NOT one-to-one, then 
$$
N=N_1+N_2.
$$
But you know $N$ and $N_1$, so...

Comment: Was over thinking it, thanks!